# Authentication for BasicHttpBinding using Request Hearder

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, request-headers, basichttpbinding

I have a `BasicHttpBinding` `WCF` service. I want to get user name and password in request header. I searched in in the internet for this but I see just `WSHttpBinding`. I want to have something like this:

```
 //WCF client call
 WCFTestService.ServiceClient myService = new
 WCFTestService.ServiceClient();
 myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
 myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "p@ssw0rd";
 MessageBox.Show(myService.GetData(123));
 myService.Close();
```

but I don't know what should I write for server side?

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/879478/BasicHttpBinding-with-Custom-Authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom Authorization Class by inheriting the [ServiceAuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class and pull out the credentials from the request header.

Your code could be similar to the following:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:  
        var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
        if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
        {
            var svcCredentials = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
                .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                .Split(':');
            var user = new
            {
                Name = svcCredentials[0],
                Password = svcCredentials[1]
            };
            if ((user.Name == "username" && user.Password == "p@ssw0rd"))
            {
                //User is authorized and originating call will proceed  
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //not authorized  
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:  
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"YourNameSpace\"");
            //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401  
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to that, you need to set the `serviceAuthorizationManagerType` attribute of the `serviceAuthorization` element to your custom class in the web.config file.

Something similar to this:

```
<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="YourNameSpace.CustomAuthorizationManager, YourAssemblyName"/>
```

In the client side, you also need to add the credentials to the request headers.

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpReqProp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpReqProp.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username"+ ":" + "p@ssw0rd"));
```

**Security note:**

Keep in mind that in Basic Authentication, the username and password will be sent as non-encrypted text in the request header. You should only implement this with SSL.

Comment: Thanks, How I can add last code to `Request Header`?